# Datastore in Remote Shell For Google App Engine (GAE) not working with zsh

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, zsh

I am trying to run a query within the remote shell of Google App Engine (GAE) Python standard, and I get an zsh abort when trying to query datastore from the shell. No errors printed to the terminal, but the python shell is terminated. Any thoughts on how I can debug this?

```
App Engine remote_api shell
Python 2.7.16 (default, Jun  5 2020, 22:59:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.29.20) (-macos10.15-objc-
The db, ndb, users, urlfetch, and memcache modules are imported.
m~staging> from models import Model
m~staging> Model.query().get()
zsh: abort      python ~/dev/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/remote_api_shell.py
```

Comment: Did you try with bash to make sure that zsh is the problem?

Comment: seems to be a remote_shell issue. I get an abort trap 6 with bash

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue. There was an old dependency for the `cryptography` package that needed to be updated. Once I did that all was resolved, both for bash and zsh.